# Burninate or alias [flotcharts]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

The [flotcharts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flotcharts) tag has the exact same description as the [flot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flot) tag. It had 6 questions, and they were all tagged with [flot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flot) too, so i just removed the [flotcharts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flotcharts) tag.

Since this tag no longer has any questions, and is already covered by another tag, I suggest it gets removed or aliased.

Comment: whots wrong with the tg?

Comment: Tags  without questions get removed at 03:00 UTC....automagically...

Comment: @rene That I didn't know. I'll just sit back, relax and watch this tag disappear all by itself then.